# Deadlock when multiple Spring batch Jobs trying to update the same record but for different column value

Tags: sql-server, spring-batch, database-deadlocks

I have spring batch based different ETl jobs which write into the same table (Db : sql server). At the same time, sometimes the jobs write into same record but they update different column of same record. This results in deadlock. How to avoid it?

this is a report table which has aggregated metrics of different parameters as column values. And for every parameter a batch job calculates the metrics and updates the record for the given market and distribution center (primary key).

Is there any isolation level or config that can be used or is it a design flaw? suggestions to improve?

Comment: Please [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71186105/edit) your question to include the actual error message you're getting - as text. It's not uncommon for people to confuse Locks and Deadlocks but they are not the same thing.

Comment: Add the deadlock report xml to your question as well as links to the execution plans uploaded to [Paste The Plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/). Deadlocks may be due due to suboptimal plans.